# Is there any way to install android app without having internet?

Tags: installation

I just bought a Samsung Galaxy Mini S, but I don't have 3g or wi-fi internet - I have internet only on my computer. Is there any way to install android apps without internet, via bluetooth or using the USB cable? (I do have bluetooth on my computer).

If it's possible to install the apps than where could I download the apps? The Market doesn't let me download them to my computer.

Comment: And you haven't considered something like Internet Connection Sharing to get your phone on your laptop's internet connection? That would be the easiest way IMO.

Comment: Two questions: 1. how to install 2. Where to get.

Answer (score 17):

Yes: you can connect the phone to your computer via USB, click the notification on your phone to mount the USB storage to the PC, move downloaded apps from your computer to your phone (easiest if you put them on the SD card), and browse on your phone to where you put the apps and click on them to install them.

Your phone should have a file browser, but if it doesn't I recommend [Explorer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.speedsoftware.explorer).  You'll need to enable **Unknown Sources** in `Settings -> Applications` as well.  You can download apps to your PC most easily from alternative markets like [GetJar](http://www.getjar.com/).

If you have installed something like Download Crutch so that you can download any type of file, or are using a non-stock browser that will ignore Android's restriction on downloads, then you can of course just download the .apk's directly to your device and skip the PC.

Comment: You can also transfer the files from PC to device via Bluetooth, and then those files will be in the folder `/sdcard/bluetooth`.

Comment: *"Your phone should have a file browser, but if **it doesn't** I recommend Explorer."* - very well. And How do I install *Explorer*? I guess you didn't think about that...

Answer (score 4):

If your computer has internet access via ethernet, and also has a wireless adaptor, you can use [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/download-lite/) to set up your own wifi hotspot for your phone to connect to. You can then download and install apps normally.

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can download from Google Play to your computer. All you need is the Google Chrome Extension - APK Downloader. Just select an app on Google Play then on the top right corner will have the APK Downloader symbol. Click it and download the app in .apk format. Then just transfer the app to your phone with either Bluetooth or USB then install the app like normal using App Installer on your phone. Simple way to install is just click on the file in your phone then click Install.

Also when you are trying to use the APK Downloader. They will ask for a Device ID for your phone. Enter *#*#8255#*#* in your phone dialer then you will see your device ID. Just insert your name, E-mail and Device ID in the APK Downloader settings in extension list and you can use it.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem when I brought the Android Smart Phone.

There is no way to download the apps to your Computer from Android Market. You should have internet on your mobile to download the apps directly to your mobile.

There are some websites where you can download the apps into your Computer.

For Ex: [Mobiles24](http://www.mobiles24.com/), [GetAndroidStuff](http://getandroidstuff.com/), etc..

And more over some of the Android Apps need internet connection to work.

Answer (score -1):

install MOBOGENIE software  fro, their official site its free and easy to use and install every app for android java etc

Comment: Would you bother to provide a link to that "official site"?